Need delay circuit to pull IC pin low for 10 seconds
For a RF project I use HT12D decoder. I have sensor with digital output. Whenever sensor value changes from low to high or high to low HT12Ds TE pin must be pulled low to enable transmission for 5-10 seconds. Then it should be released. How to do it without any IC using capacitor and transistor only. Thanks

What about resistors?

What would happen if the sensor changes states during this delay period?

What power supply voltages are available for the circuit?  Also, what are the high and low output voltages levels of the sensor?

Is this school work? If so, then please post the work you have done so far.

This is a smarthome project to detect water level of tank and report. The circuit uses battery. To improve battery life. Transmission from RF moule is preferred whenever sensor value changes for example when tank is full top level sensor ouputs high between half tank and fulltank it outputs low.

Here's a potential solution using three MOSFETs and a few peripheral components:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The edge detector produces a 10ms low pulse at each input transition, both rising and falling. Those pulses trigger a one-shot (monostable) timer to quickly charge C2, and then allow C2 to slowly discharge over many seconds, during which OUT is pulled low.
It works with a 0V/3.3V or 0V/5V digital input.

There are a few reasons not to do this using discrete components:

Input impedance is low at 10kΩ. To improve this would require another transistor and resistor.
The output rise is sluggish, and could do with more gain, or better still a schmitt trigger stage, requiring more transistors.
Switching thresholds depend heavily on transistor characteristics, which vary from device to device.
Timing precision has similar dependence on on transistor variations.
It is complicated.

There is one good thing about this design; the monostable is resettable. That is, each input edge will start the 5s cycle afresh. Apart from that, everything about this circuit could be improved with an IC.
Here's a design using ICs 74HCT1G86 and 74HC1G132:

simulate this circuit
Much simpler, and performance is superior to the non-IC design in every respect.

